# How to install Social Engineering Toolkit in mac

Tags: mac, git, hacking

I want to install SET from this link: https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit. If I am right this is the github repository. I have brew installed can't I grab it with homebrew and then use all the tools like I do in Kali?

Or the other method downloading the zip file and compiling it....but I don't know either. Basically, teach me some way with which I can install and repository from github.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to compile the SET afaik, the install is:

```
    git clone https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit
    cd social-engineer-toolkit
    python setup.py
```

now to start the setoolkit run

```
    ./setoolkit
```

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) three ways to proceed:

- run `brew search <packagename>` and, if successful, install via brew
- write your own formula for brew
- clone the repository with git and compile it yourself

For details on all three methods, it's best to consult the corresponding documentation (and come back with specific questions if you are stuck).

PS: The tool mentioned in the question is actually written in Python, so compilation will not even be necessary.